# How to remove decimal numbers in pxbax pyplot?

Tags: python, plotly

How can you **remove the decimals** of a **px.bar plot** with the library **pyplot**?

With the following dataframe:

```
Categoria   Importe
0   OTROS   1498.60
1   alquiler    150.00
2   compra_internet 740.36
3   deportes    909.87
4   recurrente  142.55
5   restaurantes    131.75
6   servicios   405.98
7   supermercado    592.26
8   transporte  663.31
```

I execute the next cell to crear a bar grapich with pyplot.

```
fig = px.bar(df_cuatri[df_cuatri['Tipo']=='gasto'].groupby(['Categoria'], as_index = False).sum(),
             x='Categoria', y='Importe', title='Último cuatrimestre', color='Categoria', text='Importe')
fig.update_layout(xaxis={'categoryarray' : ['alquiler', 'servicios', 'supermercado', 'deportes']})

fig.show()
```

With the parameter text='Importe' I am able to set the value on each bar, but it has many decimal, like: 663.310000000001. How can I round those values? The column of the dataframe is already round.

[image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raDn4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of the annotation text is specified by update_traces(texttemplate='').

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
Categoria   Importe
0   OTROS   1498.60
1   alquiler    150.00
2   compra_internet 740.360000004
3   deportes    909.8700000000001
4   recurrente  142.55
5   restaurantes    131.75
6   servicios   405.98
7   supermercado    592.259999999
8   transporte  663.310000000001
'''

df_cuatri = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)

import plotly.express as px

fig = px.bar(df_cuatri,
             x='Categoria', y='Importe', title='Último cuatrimestre', color='Categoria', text='Importe')
fig.update_layout(xaxis={'categoryarray' : ['alquiler', 'servicios', 'supermercado', 'deportes']})

fig.update_traces(texttemplate='%{text:.2f}')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The data provided was not enough to deal with the problem, so I made the values similar to the data in the image to deal with the problem. If my response is helpful to you, please click the check mark in the response to accept the answer.